# How to test a method that calls another class' method?

Tags: unit-testing, rhino-mocks, mspec

I'm fairly new to unit testing. I've recently encountered a problem where I test a method that does one thing only - it calls a method of an object that's part of the class. The class that this object represents has it's own unit tests.

I understand that this [method may change in time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967697/should-you-unit-test-simple-properties), and when it does the test should inform me about if the expected result it. But what can I test in such a method?

My code:

```
public class MyClassToBeTested
{
    private CustomType myObject;

    private const myParameter = 2;
    (...)
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return myObject.DoYourStuff(myParameter);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you need to capture the call to the underlying object and inspect it (or at least verify that the call has been made). I would [mock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) this object and inject a reference to it ([Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)).

By injecting the object you can provide the real object at deploy time, and the mock during testing.

Answer (score 0):

If something is dependent on something else. i.e. method calls another method, then you should mock it, or simulate its behaviour.

Comment: I know, but in this situation (I added a code example) I only call the method to get its result and automatically return it. I don't need the result further in the test, so I don't think mocking will help me...

Comment: So what is the purpose of your test ? In TDD world not everything needs to be tested.

Comment: We (my team) value code coverage in unit tests and recently I read in a mentioned link that I should test it anyway, just in case the property changes. I do have a problem, since I don't know what that test's going to prove.